# How to find equivalent text in another with aggregated text?

Tags: javascript, regex, react-native

**Given:**

```
const textToFind = 'Lorem Ipsum has been the industry&apos;s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, '

const paragraph = 'Lorem Ipsum has been the industry&apos;s [standard](wwww.meh.com) dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.'
```

**I require to output:**

`Lorem Ipsum has been the industry&apos;s [standard](wwww.meh.com) dummy text ever since the 1500s,`

i.e. match the `textToFind` on `paragraph` and then extract it.

I have figured out this regex to find markdown links: `/\[([^\]]+)\]\([^)"]+\)/g`, but I'm not sure what else to do after that.

`textToFind` is derived from `paragraph` in the beginning, and I need it to calculate the width of each line, thus why I'm not considering modifying `standard` to some unique identifier (so as to replace it later with the real text), because if the characters change, then so will the width.

**Additional Info:**

I am using  [React Native Text](https://reactnative.dev/docs/text#ontextlayout)'s

```
<Text onTextLayout={....} numberOfLines={x} />
```

to obtain the lines rendered in a paragraph `x`, but this text has not been converted from markdown (if so, the links are lost, since it only parses pure text, not `View`s, not `Text` properties, etc.)

**Currently:**

I am thinking of encrypting the `[plainText](url)`

(e.g. `reversePlainText().QueueShiftTwoCharacters()`),

and save this encryption in a parallel

```
recordedLinks = Queue<Record<encryptedPlainText, originalUnparsedMarkdown>>()`
```

and consults **it** in order.

This way, when going from `[plainText](url)` to `encryptedPlainText` (and *almost* losing the url and positioning), we can match `recordedLinks` in order as the screen renders each <strike>of these pieces of cryptic runics</strike> line of text, it will give `encryptedPlainText`s their links in a FIFO way.

Comment: can you provide the sample output given the input you shared?

Comment: @lemon It's in the description `Lorem Ipsum has been the industry&apos;s [standard](wwww.meh.com) dummy text ever since the 1500s,`

Comment: You want to check if the input its in the paragraph? That output example its unclear.

Comment: I know the input is in the paragraph, but not in its original form, rather possibly containing markdown links for any of the words it has. I want to extract it with links and everything.

Comment: That's ok, I know python.

Answer (score 0):

The following is a rough and ready solution. It assumes no regex special characters in the `textToFind` (if there are they can be escaped simply enough).

A regex is created from `textToFind` where every word has the option to be the link text of a markdown link, for example `Ipsum` becomes `(?:Ipsum|\[Ipsum\]\([^)"]+\))` in the regex string.

```js
const textToFind = 'Lorem Ipsum has been the industry&apos;s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, ';

const paragraph = 'Lorem Ipsum has been the industry&apos;s [standard](wwww.meh.com) dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.'

const regexString = textToFind.replace(/\w+/g, '(?:$&|\\[$&\\]\\([^)"]+\\))');

const match = paragraph.match(new RegExp(regexString, 'g'));

console.log(match);
```

If you explain how `textToFind` is being used to calculate the width of each line then a more robust solution may be forthcoming.

Comment: This approach will work until the `textToFind` contains special regex metacharacters. If there is `(Ipsum)` instead of `Ipsum`, the return value will be `null`.

Comment: Yes, Wiktor, I mention regex special characters in my answer. It is not intended to be a water-tight solution - the OP's question is not detailed enough for that to be provided. `escapeRegExp = str => str.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&');`

Comment: @MikeM I updated the description being far more detailed. Programming sure is fun.